# Webcam is not supported in Ubuntu

Tags: drivers, webcam

I am using Ubuntu on my Vaio CR VGN-CR35G/R. I am unable to use my webcam by the button on my laptop. I have installed cheese webcam utility but that also does not recognise my webcam. What to do?

Answer (score 0):

This ppa will work: https://launchpad.net/~r5u87x-loader/+archive/ppa

Enter, and find green ppa text. and do what it say.